# Getting error 502.5 when trying to run a ASP .Net Core 2.1 Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to follow Microsofts guide on building a web app with individual user authentication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Every time I try to run the program I get an error 502.5

[error 502.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zNa8.png)

I have tried the suggestions in the comments of the guide and done a fair bit of searching for people having the same issue but I didn't find any solutions that solved my issue.

I'm not sure what could be the source of the issue but I will put up the project settings launch settings etc.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
<UserSecretsId>aspnet-ContactManager-0DAD76F8-C053-4971-A8DF-4C55A4FF198B</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>
<!-- <PropertyGroup>
<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup> -->
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils" Version="2.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.1 />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

LaunchSettings.json

[LaunchSettings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygjw8.png)

Program.cs

[Program.cs Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyjW6.png)

When the web app is running with debugging, this error is brought up.

[Run Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ooIL.png)

[Update-database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkum3.png)

If there's anything you need me to include let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

5xx codes indicate some unhandled error in the application or server itself. You should attach a debugger in your dev environment and see what the unhandled exception is, which is what I guess is happening here.

Comment: Do you mean to run it with the debugger in visual studio? If so I took this screenshot 
not sure what its telling me though. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ooIL.png] (Screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've run into this I didn't have the correct versions of Core SDK installed.  Maybe double check that?

Comment: I installed the latest version just to be sure, made sure visual studio is up to date and still running into the same error.